# Queue processing one by one using RabbitMQ

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

I have limited number of workers and unlimited number of queues named by mask "q.*" (e.g. `q.1`, `q.2`). I need to process them 
in turn. One task per one worker. When worker finished its task, it receive new one from next existing queue.

E.g. I have queues:

```
q.1: task11, task12, task13
q.2: task21, task22, task23
```

And three workers. I expect next order of executing:

```
worker1: task11
worker2: task21
worker3: task12
worker1: task22
worker2: task13
worker3: task23
```

I tried to use `topic` and subscribed to mask `q.*` but this leads to the fact that each worker receives tasks from all queues. What is correct decision?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you need this particular setup? If you need to consume just one message from a queue, then you can use either basic.qos(prefetch_count=1) or basic.get

Answer (score 0):

Think of each queue as it's own bucket of work.  q.1 has no relation to q.2 at all and in fact doesn't even know it exists.  It may process things at different rates from q.2 and should have different consumers.  A worker on q.1 should only be concerned about q.1, it shouldn't bounce back and forth between q.1 and q.2.

Are you trying to chain 2 queues together?  If so you could have something like this:

1. Message gets put into q.1
2. Message is processed by a worker (call it worker1) of q.1
3. After worker1 acks the message it then inserts a new message into q.2
4. Message is processed by a worker (call it worker2) of q.2